# Using CURL connect only

Tags: http, curl, connect

I am looking at testing a connection using curl and connect only. The issue i have is when looking for a response the documentation states I must use HTTP CONNECT CODE. When I look at the response it is stating 0, not 200 or 304 as I would expect.

Why is curl doing this?

Is connect only to be used only when using proxies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CURL's connect-only feature is for when you are connecting through proxies to test connection settings.

This is from the curl documentation :

```
CONNECT_ONLY tells the library to perform all the required proxy 
authentication and connection setup, but no data transfer. This option
is implemented for HTTP, SMTP and POP3
```